# Search from comma separated values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table with 2 columns - `id` and `pets`.

Pets column contain abbreviated pet names separated by , [comma] as shown below

```
+----+-------------+
| id | pets        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | CAT,DOG     |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | CAT,DOG,TIG |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | ZEB,MOU     |
+----+-------------+
```

Now I want to list all id's where pets = CAT, similarly all id's where pets = DOG etc

My initial try was to RUN the following SQL for each and every PET (CAT, DOG, etc)

```
select id
from "favpets"
where pets like '%CAT%'
```

The limitation of this simple solution is that the actual table and no. of pets are not as simple as mentioned above.

No. of such pets are more than 200. Therefore, 200 sql's have to be executed in order to list all id's corresponding to the pets

Is there any good alternative solution ? I'm using doctrine, so does doctrine provide any good implementation ?

Comment: Do you want a query for each pet in pets? My solution is to create another table with each row corresponding to an unique pet and then join those two tables

Comment: @PresidentCamacho, your solution will work, but I think with postgresql and array functions there are more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query you will obtain all id, all pets, ordered by pet:

```
SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(pets, ',')) AS mypet
FROM favpets
ORDER BY mypet;
```

Using it as subquery it will became easy to group and count:

```
SELECT mypet, COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(pets, ',')) AS mypet
    FROM favpets
    ORDER BY mypet
) AS a
GROUP BY mypet;
```

Comment: What is _a_ in the second query ?

Comment: Just an example where you can find how many time a pet is listed. To answer your primary question, probably first query is ok for you.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the suggestion. Infact, I need second query for my implementation.

Comment: Do you also need id's in second query? You can aggregate them if you need.

Comment: A in the second query is an alias.